# Divs getting out of the screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a serie of divs inside another div:

```
<section id="process">
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Así trabajo.</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-padding">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-centered">
            <i class="fa fa-align-justify fa-5x"></i>
            <h4>Estructuración.</h4>
            <p>Mi código es limpio y sencillo, podrás modificarlo fácilmente si así lo deseas.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-centered">
            <i class="fa fa-align-justify fa-5x"></i>
            <h4>Estructuración.</h4>
            <p>Mi código es limpio y sencillo, podrás modificarlo fácilmente si así lo deseas.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-centered">
            <i class="fa fa-align-justify fa-5x"></i>
            <h4>Estructuración.</h4>
            <p>Mi código es limpio y sencillo, podrás modificarlo fácilmente si así lo deseas.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-centered">
            <i class="fa fa-align-justify fa-5x"></i>
            <h4>Estructuración.</h4>
            <p>Mi código es limpio y sencillo, podrás modificarlo fácilmente si así lo deseas.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

I've tried adding a rule in css but it didn't work:

```
.row {
        height: 100%;
}
```

and:

```
#process{
height: 100%
}
```

All I want is that those divs fits 100% of the screen and doesn't get out of the current resolution.

Comment: Could you clarify if you're trying to make a row fill 100% of the screen height, or if you're having horizontal issues?

Comment: I'm having horizontal issues, they are getting out of the screen and that cause troubles like sliding horizontal bar appearing or divs not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

**HTML**

```
<div class="row row-padding custom-class">
```

**CSS**

```
.custom-class {
  margin: 0;
}
```

to overwrite

```
.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
```

[**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/ymDz75pC9g)